# host file not working after running Fiddler 4.6.20171.14978

Tags: fiddler

today i've installed Fiddler 4.6.20171.14978 everything works fine but after closing fiddler my host file wont work and none of my records react to the custom ip , i have tested it on windows 10, windows 8.1 , windows 7 
even after uninstalling host file not working any more :( any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools => Hosts => Tick on Enable remapping of requests for one host to a different host of IP, overriding DNS => click on Import windows host file => Save